# Booting system without full network configuration, how to reverse?

Tags: boot, networking, configuration, ethernet

Hi I am running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and I have not been able to connect to the internet through a cable from the satellite. So I found the following advice:

start the terminal and type
gksu gedit /etc/network/interfaces
File will opened in gedit. It will be empty or should contain 
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
In gedit add following lines and save it and close
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
and restart the network manager It works fine with my case

So I followed it and now ubuntu says "waiting for network configuration", followed by "Booting system without full network configuration". It takes a few minutes to start the computer now. It also got rid of the little connection icon that normally lets me know if networks are in range or if a wire is plugged in. My question is how do I reverse this? And is there a way to be able to connect to the internet through the wire.
Your help would be greatly appreciated. I am completely new to this and it was my first attempt at using the terminal and it back fired ;)

Thank you so much, Sandra

Answer (score 0):

To undo it you can remove the lines that the guide had you add to the /etc/network/interfaces file, and restart the network manager.

However, it sounds like you're not getting an IP address. I don't know how you'd plug directly into a satellite, but if you're plugging into a router (which is plugged into a satellite) I suggest rebooting it and waiting a few minutes (and then restarting your pc or network manager) to see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

So you basically say you're using a desktop version of Ubuntu otherwise you wouldn't have the network manager icon. In order to get this configuration working you'll need to make the file /etc/network/interfaces empty and add network connections using your network manager tool.